# Корректное создание url-ссылки на ресурс

Tags: python, django, url

Есть у меня ссылка на картинку, которая находится в папке с проектом. В ней находится папка Static/Image. В последней лежат картинки. Когда хочу вывести любую картинку через код:

```
<img scr = "/Static/Image/1.jpg">
```

...то у меня вылазит ошибка, т.к. проект сам меняет URL и в начало добавляет папку `Blog`, то есть ищет картинку по адресу `Blog/Static/Image/1.jpg` а её там нету! Как сделать так, что бы каждый раз `Blog` не добавлялся?

Comment: Использую Django

Comment: Нужно в url добавить пути, и вообще сделать collectstatic, почитай тут: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 3):

Убедитесь, что у вас правильно указан путь до статики в `settings.py`.
Должно быть `STATIC_URL = '/Static/'`, по умолчанию он указан с маленькой буквы, у вас название директории с большой.
В шаблонах следуюет использовать темплейт тег `static`
Сверху в шаблоне укажите: `{% load staticfiles %}`
Путь до изображения: `<img scr = "{% static 'Image/1.jpg' %}">`

Comment: А как быть, если у меня:
<img scr = "{{ post.images.url }}">

Comment: У меня картинки лежат по адресу "Static/Image", но  использую именно "post.images.url". Когда я это делаю, то у меня путь к картинке меняется, и перед самой ссылкой автоматически добавляется левая папка "blog". Как сделать так, что бы при использовании:
<img scr = "{{ post.images.url }}">
НЕ добавлялся blog ?